# Searchengine with php and mysql does not retrieve data with greek characters

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I made a site that contains data in English and some rows contain Greek characters.

When it searches in english with one letter it returns the data correctly but when you search in greek it doesn't return any data.

I made the charset utf8 in the db connection and in the table also and in the main page of showing the content.

Here is the code:

```
$product=$_POST['product_name'];

$protrace=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `status`='$status' AND `proname` LIKE '%". $product."%'  ORDER BY `proname` LIMIT 0,10 ;");
```

Comment: The question is not very clear. Could you rephrase it and give data exemple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this after establishing connection to your MySQL database.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

<sup>`Sidenote : Stop using mysql_* functions. Switch to PreparedStatements.`</sup>

Comment: thanks and also there was an error that i added attribute to the form to accept another charset.... all working now